# Simple fetch for kitty img

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, fetch-api

idk what I did with my code, but yesterday this fetch was working. I extract a kitty pic from API.
Today when i tried its not working, it says that url is not defined. Same problem have my friend from bootcamp. Something happens with a API.

```js
function getKitties() {
  fetch("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search")
    .then((response) => {
      (response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        (console.log(response)

        )
      })
      var cat = response[0].url;
    })
  var imgcat = document.createElement("img");
  imgcat.src = cat;
  var dtag = document.createAttribute("data-tag");
  dtag.value = "img-kitty";
  imgcat.setAttributeNode(dtag);
  imgcat.innerHTML = " "
  document.body.appendChild(imgcat);

}
```

```html
<button id="searchKitty" onclick="getKitties()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: [Working Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/SwdfR896rWI8eI6t?open=lib%2Fscript.js) - try to compare your javascript code with the one in the demo. That should give you an idea of why your code isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the action into the THEN

Here is a version that is using recommended methods, addEventListener and catch and also a simplified data attribute

```js
document.getElementById('searchKitty').addEventListener('click', e => {
  fetch('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      var cat = response[0].url;
      var imgcat = document.createElement("img");
      imgcat.src = cat;
      imgcat.dataset.tag = "img-kitty";
      imgcat.setAttribute("alt",response[0].breeds.join("") || "Cat")
      document.body.appendChild(imgcat)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
})
```

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button id="searchKitty" type="button">Click me</button>
<hr/>
```

Comment: You probably should fix the promise-chaining - no need to nest `then()` method call inside the callback function of the first `then()` method when you can just return `response.json()` from the first `then()` method's callback and chain the second `then()` method instead of nesting it and ideally there should be a `catch()` method as well.

Comment: @Yousaf Thanks, I missed that. I have streamlined the code now